# Samsung Galaxy S3 not booting up, keeps restarting showing ”Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-i9300” black screen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, boot-loop

My Samsung S3 is stuck! It keeps restarting!

It doesn't reach the enter pincode, but keeps restarting showing the "Samsung Galaxy S3 i9300" screen. Then cycles starts again.

Here are the things I've tried:

- I have already removed battery, put back in; still the same result.
- I have also tried to hard-reset, but it just turns off and restarts.
- Same result when trying VOLUME DOWN + HOME + POWER BUTTON; goes back to restarting and the Samsung S3 screen.

It was working fine last night, but when I left to do something, I came back and found it restarting over and over again. Didn't update any apps.

Comment: I had this same problem and I had to boot the phone in safe mode. I did it by using this video. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNngD92p_GE

Answer (score 7):

Enter recovery and delete dalvik/cache. To enter *recovery* you have to hold `Volume up + Home + Power` (The same with `Volume down` is *download mode*). Once in recovery, select the option to wipe cache/dalvik, then restart the phone.

If the phone keeps rebooting as it was doing before, try searching the log of the boot sequence to see if you can find where it fails. You will need a PC with [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) installed and the phone's USB cable.

1. With the phone off, open a `CMD` window in your PC, go to *Android SDK* directory and run `adb logcat`
2. Turn on your phone and connect the USB cable.
3. You should en seeing in your cmd window the log of the phone as it boots.
4. Once it enters a boot loop, you should be able to check the log and see what it tries to do and can't do (that triggers the boot loop).