# Galaxy S3 stuck on Samsung logo, is there anyway i can backup my data in recovery mode without rooting?

Tags: backup, root-access, recovery-mode

i have the original Firmware, no rooting. Recently, i got this issue where my s3 doesn't startup, it just keeps flashing the logo over and over again until the battery drains. I've already tried pulling the battery, wiping cache partition several times but no luck.

So is it possible to root my device without losing any data or at least can i backup from the recovery mode?

I'm an Android newbie, so i have zero background on this stuff. What am i suppose to do ?

Edit: i'm specifically asking about backing up my data, is it possible?

Comment: Similar issue here: [Galaxy S3 stuck on boot loop, Factory Reset didn't work](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42275/16575). Maybe the answers there help you out?

Comment: thanks, i've already seen it. I'm just worried about losing my data, is it possible to backup in recovery mode without rooting?

Comment: Stock recovery doesn't offer a backup option. You could try whether the device is discovered by ADB while in recovery mode. If so, you should be able to use `adb backup`. See our [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info) for some details.

Comment: How were you able to back up your device? I'm having the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

Boot into odin mode, plug into laptop,  get custom recovery and root via odin (this doesn't wipe data) then in the custom recovery do a nandroid backup then clear dalvik cache and try to boot. If this doesn't work then sorry you're gonna need to flash a custom rom or stock rom again

Comment: Thanks, i installed CWM, but clearing dalvik cache didn't do any good, so i backed up my device and made a factory reset and finally my device booted and was no longer stuck at the logo. All my photos, videos and music were safe and sound, however, all my apps were gone, as well as my contacts and text mesages. I appreciate your help :).

Comment: Yea no problem if you're rooted now get titanium backup