# Boot loop on Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

In response to the question on the link below Peter asked that one run adb catlog in the Android SDK. I managed to download the Android SDK but I cannot locate the adb catlog file. Can I get help to locate this file in the standard Android SDK folder? Another question once the cause of the looping has been located does the file automatically remove it or there is something you need to do?

[Samsung Galaxy S3 not booting up, keeps restarting showing ”Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-i9300” black screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38775/samsung-galaxy-s3-not-booting-up-keeps-restarting-showing-samsung-galaxy-s3-gt?rq=1)

Comment: Your title and the body text aren't in agreement here. This makes the question hard to answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for `adb logcat` output, it's not necessarily stored on a file in the Android SDK directory.

In order to access it, follow the following steps (assuming you have the SDK installed correctly):

**1:** Plug in your phone.

**2:** Type `adb devices` in your Terminal or CMD Prompt

- If you get a result like "Command not found", you may need to navigate to the platform-tools/ directory inside the SDK folder using the `cd [directory]` command.
- If you get a "List of connected devices" result, but the list is empty, then you have a configuration error. You may need drivers for your phone, etc...

**3:** Type `adb logcat`. The Terminal/CMD Prompt will begin to output logcat messages in real time. You can do what you want with the output, including save it to a file.